# Stripe refund in PHP not working

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement a refund using stripe php and the API doc says to do like this

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(Test_KEY);

$re = \Stripe\Refund::create(array(
  "charge" => "charge_id"
));
```

but whent I test it, I get this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Stripe\Refund::create()

Am I missng something? Even if I copy-paste, I get that error from a code taken directly from the API guide..

Comment: You're likely not on Stripe-php v 3.2.0 this was just added to the library yesterday

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I updated the Stripe API about 5 hours ago.

Comment: You need to update the api library not the api itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out the issue, in fact I think only those who did not install stripe with composer will get this error. Basically, you have to download the latest version as well, either stripe-master or stripe-3-2-0 from github. I just uploaded the latest release, replaced my old one and working like a charm.
[Get it here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases)

Answer (score 0):

use \Stripe\Stripe;

in starting of page then implement.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(Test_KEY);
$re = \Stripe\Refund::create(array(
"charge" => "charge_id"
));
```